# Determine network connection

Tags: networking, wifi, network-protocols, packet, lan

Suppose there are multiple WiFi networks, with names A1, A2, A3, ..., in a building. Computer C is connected to one of them. The user of the computer C is sending me packets and claiming to be using network A1 to send me the packets. Is there a way for me to confirm whether the user is telling the truth, i.e. confirm the name of the network computer C is connected to? How about the same question for LAN networks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each WIFI network is provided by a different WIFI access point. Each access point has it's own IP address. You could do a **trace route** from your computer towards the target, analyze the list of IP addresses you get from that trace, and determine which access point is in the list... if it appears in the list at all, which is not safe. If so, then you just need to find out, how to program a trace route...
Analyzing the IP packets won't help you much, as they don't contain any information about WIFI networks. The only other solution could be, if the computers were at different subnets.

Comment: Thanks. What did you mean by " if it appears in the list at all, which is not safe."? Do you mean I might not be able to get the IP addresses of the access points? When I do a trace route can I see the name (XYZ Inc WiFi) of the access point in addition to its IP address (123.456.789.000)?

Comment: The problem is, that the AP almost always is completely transparent to the computers on the network. Search for "tracert accesspoint" or "find out IP address of accesspoint". As this is difficult already, I doubt that you will find a way to detect, which AP a computer is connected to. So, no, you will likely not see the AP in the trace route.

Comment: But you could have success if you used other hardware, which is made for business use and has managment functions (e.g. managed switches etc).